# Im using joomla for my site but thats loading too slow, i dont know why, who can help me please

Tags: jquery

My website is http://www.seoitc.com im using joomla 2.5, strong server, but my website allway loadding too long on home page, i tried optimized html + images but thats still slow, i dont know why, who can help me please?
Thanks you!

Comment: Get Chrome and run an audit on the page. I wait three seconds for your server to send back the data, so consider caching your pages.

Comment: (And good luck w/ the copyrighted Hot Topic logo image.)

Answer (score 3):

The reason your site is so slow is because of a lot of factors, without going into everything here is just some of the major issues which if you resolve should see a increase.

Your server is hosted in the US
IP Address: 98.129.***.***

So I ran lots of tests from US based servers and one from EU.

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/121212_03_PKH/

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/121212_VJ_PKQ/

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/121212_K2_PN1/

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/121212_D5_PNH/

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/121212_J2_PNP/

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/121212_BN_PQF/

**Host**
The host you are using is extremely slow and you should change at once, it has a first byte issue (The time it takes for the server to acknowledge someone is accessing the site for the first time, can also be DNS too)

**Java-scripts**
You have a crazy amount of JavaScript for what your site does, a lot of the JavaScript is not even being used, since you are Joomla you can publish the JavaScript into modules using CUSTOM HTML and position them in footer, furthermore you should only publish those java scripts on the pages that use those, for example its pointless having JavaScript for a gallery execute on FrontPage if the gallery is only used on one page and its not the FrontPage.

Inline; Try to use as little inline code as you can so you can minifiy it, and gzip it. This applies to CSS too.

Furthermore you are loading an old version of Jquery and a Newer Version, Your effectively loading 2 Jquery LIBs which you should only be using one.

**Images**
You need to optimise your images and learn what images are best in what format, for example you have GIF's for your slider when a Jpeg Lossless Compressed Image would be more fitting and save more BW therefor giving more speed back to your users, also there seems to be an issue that the images are being reloaded more than once on those Sliders, Looks like an Ajax request.

PNG files are great for things like menus, icons and so on but you should try and use a PNG sprite to reduce the amount of files that need to be requested. Look up PNG Sprite in CSS.

**CSS**
At the moment you are using 5 CSS files, you should try and make this 1 with no Inline.

The Main Issue is your web host and then resolve the other issues.

****ADDITIONAL NOTES:****
*There also seems to be lag from switching from / to /en/ so you might want to investigate the code/plugin you have used to make that redirect.*